# java.lang.StackOverflowError in RAD for JUnit-JMockit tests

Tags: java, junit, rad, jmockit, stack-overflow

When running a JUnit test that are mocked with JMockit, we are receiving the following error in RAD from few developer machines. The test runs fine in other machines and in our continuous integration server. Any pointers to what to lookout for?

We are running by adding the required VM arguments -  `-javaagent:../<project_lib_dir>/jmockit.jar`

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:248)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:149)
at mockit.internal.state.TestRun$1.set(TestRun.java:61)
at mockit.internal.state.TestRun$1.set(TestRun.java:54)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:156)
at mockit.internal.state.TestRun$1.set(TestRun.java:61)
at mockit.internal.state.TestRun$1.set(TestRun.java:54)
at mockit.internal.state.TestRun.enterNoMockingZone(TestRun.java:168)
at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.SharedFieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineTypesForTestClass(SharedFieldTypeRedefinitions.java:49)
at mockit.integration.TestRunnerDecorator.handleMockFieldsForWholeTestClass(TestRunnerDecorator.java:127)
at mockit.integration.TestRunnerDecorator.updateTestClassState(TestRunnerDecorator.java:46)
at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.invokeExplosively(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)`
```

Comment: Sudhin, I suggest that you compare the versions of the JVMs, versions of junit and versions of JMockit used to run the tests where they work against the versions of the JVMs that display the error and update the question with this information.

Comment: Thanks Rob. That did the trick. I assumed the JVMs are the same. Somebody ran an update on some of the machines. Changed the configs and the tests are running in all the machines now.

Comment: Sudhin, it's a pleasure, I'm happy to help. Will add the comment as an answer.